# How to always show hidden files in powershell

Tags: powershell

```
dir -force
```

shows hidden files.

Is there a way to make dir always show hidden files without the option force?

I tried Set-Alias but this doesn't work

```
Set-alias -Name la -Value "dir -force"
```

Comment: `function la { dir -force }` <-- you have to declare a function, not an alias. Put in in your PowerShell-Profile to have it loaded by default. https://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare a function, not an alias.

```
function la {
    Param($path = ".")
    dir $path -Force
}
```

Put it in your [PowerShell Profile](https://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/)  to have it loaded by default when you open PowerShell.

You can use this function like this `la` or `la C:\windows` or `la C:\windows, K:\somewhere`